# Parsing data sent from server, TextViews not showing up?

Tags: android, json, parsing

I think it's very odd that the TextViews are not showing me any data that it has retrieved from the mySQL database. Here is my code:

This is the key parsing bit, I have two columns that need parsing and putting into separate TextView, something that I think I have done:

```
//PARSING JSON DATA
        try {
            jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.i("log_name", "Driver_full_name:" + json_data.getString("Driver_full_name"));
                Log.i("log_for", "Drives for:" + json_data.getString("Drives_for"));

                returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                somethingelse += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            Log.d("DB", "Error somewhere");
            CurrentSeasonDrivers_DriverName.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(CurrentSeasonDrivers_DriversName, "Could not parse data so shut up",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }

        return returnString += somethingelse;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String returnString, String somethingelse) {

            TextView drivername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DriverName);
            drivername.setText(drivername.getText() + "\n" + returnString);

            TextView drivesfor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DrivesFor);
            drivesfor.setText(drivesfor.getText() + "\n" + somethingelse);

    }
}
}
```

Hoping someone can help. Considering there are no errors. The logs in the parsing bit show the data fully parsed, however the logs in the onPostExecute show it unparsed again, or at least with curly brackets and speech marks around each row.

Thanks for any help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're parsing the JSON using the `getString` method for your logs, but stuffing the entire JSON in the Strings that you use to set the text.  Unless there's something in between these steps that's not here, I think what you need to do is use the `getString` method when appending to returnString and somethingElse.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `onPostExecute` method even called? The signature is wrong, it cannot take two parameters.

You should pass a String array instead (and of course change your `AsyncTask` class declaration to use a String array in `onPostExecute`) :

```
    ...
    return new String[] {returnString, somethingelse};
}

protected void onPostExecute(String[] strings) {
    String returnString = strings[0];
    String somethingelse = strings[1];
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on the return values; it wants me to change my doinBackground to string[] however to declare ArrayList<String> in my Async declaration wants it to be ArrayList<String>

Comment: Why do you want to declare it as an `ArrayList` ? Just change your AsyncTask declaration to return String[].

Comment: Oops, been following other tutorials that work with Arrays, presumed that's what you meant. I ran the app and it still shows the data with curly brackets and speech marks around the text. The curly brackets are around each row of the database. The logs "log_name" and log_for show the data in plain text. Actually one thing to possibly note; the logs are showing the data rows. I'm assigning all log_names to one textview but the data is showing in the log as follows log_name, log_for, log_name, log_for etc. ALl in a list